# Background change on button when pressed, isn't working properly

Tags: android

This is my xml file for the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/play_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/play" />
</selector>
```

But this only works only one time, when I go to another activity and return then this doesn't work.

When I first run the activity the background of the button changes as it should, but when i go to another activity and return back to the previous one, then the background change while button pressed isn't working....

**EDIT:**

The problem was in my java code. It was replacing the background to a static `png` image every-time (except the first time)...The above code works as it is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/play_default" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/play_pressed" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/play_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Comment: then you have to save button state for that.